# Displaying ping request to html font end with javascript and python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am a super beginner to programming so I have had ChatGPT help me build this toolbox. The one thing I cannot get to work right now is having a few buttons ping servers (localhost for testing) and display the response to the front end. Anything I am missing here?

```
<h2>Server Status:</h2>
    <div class="button-container server-status">
        <h3>DNS East:</h3>
        <button class="server-button" data-location="DNS East" data server="localhost">Localhost</button>
        <button class="server-button" data-location="DNS East" data-server="server1">server1</button>
        <button class="server-button" data-location="DNS East" data-server="server2">server2</button>
    </div>
```

```
// Add event listeners to server status buttons
document.querySelectorAll('.server-status button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const location = button.parentElement.querySelector('h3').textContent.trim();
        const server = button.textContent.trim();
        getServerStatus(location, server, button.parentElement); // Pass parent element as parameter
    });
});

function getServerStatus(location, server, parentElement) {
    // Make a GET request to the Flask route to get the server status
    fetch(`/server_status/${location}/${server}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            // Display the server status on the screen
            const statusDiv = document.createElement('div');
            statusDiv.textContent = `${server}: ${data}`;
            if (data.includes('1 packets received')) {  // Check for the specific pattern indicating a successful ping response
                statusDiv.style.color = 'green';  // Set text color to green
            } else {
                statusDiv.style.color = 'red';  // Set text color to red
            }
            parentElement.appendChild(statusDiv);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

```
# Server Status Dictionary
SERVER_STATUS = {
    'DNS East': ['localhost', 'server1', 'server2']
}

# Ping Server Function
def ping_server(server):
    """Ping the specified server and return the result."""
    command = ['ping', '-c', '1', server]  # Linux command for pinging a server once
    result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout  # Return the ping result
```

I think it might be something on the frontend or JS side but I am not sure yet.